# Can I access a global variable value in other requisition?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have an API Restful c# that 2 player can connect to play my game multiplayer, I want to create a global variable to know if there is a player to play. If the other player connect to the api the value of global value resets ?
Like this

```
bool hasPlayer = false;
        bool playing = false;

    public bool connect()
    {
        if (hasPlayer)
        {
            playing = true;
            return true; //to start sending the game informations
        }
        else
        {
            hasPlayer = true;
            while (!playing)
            {
                //wait
            }

            return true;  //to start sending the game informations
        }


    }
```

Comment: Yes if you have the instance of the class it belong to.

Comment: 1. You can use static, 2. You can inject a singleton using DI. 3. You can store information in a DB

Comment: there´s really no such thing in .NET as a global variable, as .NET is an object-oriented language. Things don´t live in an empty airless space, they have relationships between one another. The closest thing here is a static field within a class.